# How to insert data from 2 different Webform in 1 table simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql, webforms

First, i run Request.aspx and add data to the table. then the website send me back a response on Response.aspx which i have to add into same table in different columns.

Comment: You need to write code in both the pages. Did you do that? What issue you are facing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried writing the code in the question, it kept asking me to correcting the format.

Comment: And, I used Sqlcommand con = new Sqlcommand(Insert into table value1,value2...)Values(@value1, @value2..) and data was successfully added.